# ¿Cómo capturar el valor de un INPUT para mostrarlo en un TD?

Tags: javascript, jquery

de nuevo solicitando ayuda para poder capturar el valor del INPUT al que he llamado 'total' el cual deseo mostrar el valor en un TD al cual asignaremos como ID 'enviar_aqui'. Esto forma parte de un sistema de facturación, como verán al hacer clic en AGREGAR el contenido de los INPUT se va a otra tabla. Ahí todo bien, pero ahora necesito que valores muy especificos como el total, descuento e impuestos viajen a otra tabla, que es la que mostrará lo totalizado.

La aplicación funncional es esta:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#masfilas").click(function(){
        var qty = $("#qty");
  var upc = $("#upc");
  var nomprod = $("#nomprod");
  var precio = $("#precio");
  var discount = $("#discount");
  var impuestos = $("#impuestos");
  var total = $("#total");
        $("#mytable").append('<tr><td align="center">' + qty.val() + '</td><td align="center">' + upc.val() + '</td><td>' + nomprod.val() + '</td><td>' + precio.val() + '</td><td>' + discount.val() + '</td><td>' + impuestos.val() + '</td><td>' + total.val() + '</td><td align="center"><a href="#" class="delete" title="Eliminar línea" style="cursor:pointer;">ELIMINAR</a></td></tr>');
        $('.delete').off().click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();
        });
        qty.val("");
  upc.val("");
  nomprod.val("");
  precio.val("");
  discount.val("");
  impuestos.val("");
  total.val("");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--AQUI COMIENZO A INGRESAR LOS ARTICULOS-->
<table width="70%" align="center">
 <tr>
     <td colspan="8"><b>Agregar Artículos / Servicios:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Cantidad:</td>
        <td>Código:</td>
        <td>Nombre:</td>
        <td>Precio:</td>
        <td>Descuento (%):</td>
        <td>Impuesto:</td>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td>Opciones:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="quantity" size="5" title="Cantidad"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="upc" name="codigo" size="12" title="Código" placeholder="744105300000"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="nomprod" name="nombre" size="23" title="Nombre"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="precio" name="price" size="10" title="Precio del producto" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" size="15" title="Descuento" placeholder="0.00%"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="impuestos" class="imp" name="impuestoivi" size="15" title="Impuesto de Ventas" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="total" class="imp" name="totalizar" size="15" title="Total de Línea" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
        <td><a href="#" title="Agregar línea" id="masfilas" class="add_form_field" style="cursor:pointer;">AGREGAR</a></td><!--Al hacer clic se deberia disparar la funcion onclick-->
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="70%" align="center" border="1" id="mytable" class="table-bordered table-striped">
 <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
     <td width="70%" align="left" colspan="8"><b>RESUMEN DEL CARRITO</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td width="3%">Cantidad:</td>
        <td width="10%">Código:</td>
        <td width="13%">Nombre:</td>
        <td width="5%">Precio:</td>
        <td width="9%">Descuento (%):</td>
        <td width="10%">Impuesto:</td>
        <td width="10%">Total:</td>
        <td colspan="2" width="10%">Opciones:</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--AQUI DESEO RECIBIR EL VALOR DEL INPUT id total-->
<table width="20%" align="left" border="1">
 <tr>
     <td>Subtotal</td>
        <td id="enviar_aqui">CRC. 0.00</td><!--El valor debería caer aqui-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>- Descuento</td>
        <td>CRC. 0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Impuesto</td>
        <td>CRC. 0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Venta Total</td>
        <td>CRC. 0.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Resumiendo y en concreto, al hacer clic en AGREGAR aparte de que crea la fila que viaja a la tabla id=mytable quiero que se vaya al TD que tiene id=eviar_aqui

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, puedes resolverlo muy simple, coloca dentro de tu `td` otra etiqueta, como un `span`; cambia la linea `<td id="enviar_aqui">CRC. 0.00</td>` por `<td><span id="enviar_aqui" >CRC. 0.00</span></td>` y te saldrá.

Comment: Hola @the-breaker pues no me funcionó. Mi codigo JQuery es: $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#masfilas").click(function () {
              var total = $("#total").val();
              $("#enviar_aqui").val(total);
          });
      });

Comment: No utilices `.val()`, el `span` no es un tiene value, usa `.html()` así: `$(document).ready(function () { $("#masfilas").click(function () { var total = $("#total").val(); $("#enviar_aqui").html(total); }); });`

Comment: @the-breaker me lo manda vacío al span. Acabo de publicar el código modificado, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @the-breaker acabo de depurarlo un poco, y con un `alert` aún me devuelve un valor vacio. No entiendo porque, ya que el `id="total"` trae un valor.

Comment: Hombre en la linea `total.val("");` estas vaciando el valor. si comentas esa linea funciona bien

Comment: Sí lo tiene ese valor `total.val("");` porque necesito que en el input se borre al hacer clic `id="masfilas"`

Comment: el problema es que total se esta vaciando antes; `total.val("");` se ejecuta antes de `var total  = $("total").val();`, borra el valor de total luego de guardarlo

Comment: Así es, sin embargo te comentó que me envía el `html` del elemento `id`, ya que viaja todo el imput completo. Lo solucioné con el `append` Gracias por tu valiosa ayuda @the-breaker

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tu ayuda @the-breaker

Me lo manda al span, pero va vacío.

Aqui el ejecutable.

```js
//Resumen del carrito
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#masfilas").click(function(){
        var qty = $("#qty");
  var upc = $("#upc");
  var nomprod = $("#nomprod");
  var precio = $("#precio");
  var discount = $("#discount");
  var impuestos = $("#impuestos");
  var total = $("#total");
        $("#mytable").append('<tr><td align="center">' + qty.val() + '</td><td align="center">' + upc.val() + '</td><td>' + nomprod.val() + '</td><td>' + precio.val() + '</td><td>' + discount.val() + '</td><td>' + impuestos.val() + '</td><td>' + total.val() + '</td><td align="center"><a href="#" class="delete" title="Eliminar línea" style="cursor:pointer;">ELIMINAR</a></td></tr>');
        $('.delete').off().click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();
        });
        qty.val("");
  upc.val("");
  nomprod.val("");
  precio.val("");
  discount.val("");
  impuestos.val("");
  total.val("");
    });
});
//subtotal
   
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#masfilas").click(function () { 
    var total = $("#total").val();
   $("#enviar_aqui").html(total); }); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="70%" align="center">
 <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
     <td width="70%" align="left" colspan="2"><b>DETALLE</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td width="70%"><input type="text" name="itemsearch" id="item" size="50" placeholder="INICIAR BÚSQUEDA" title="Ingrese Nombre del Articulo" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="70%" align="center">
 <tr>
     <td colspan="8"><b>Agregar Artículos / Servicios:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Cantidad:</td>
        <td>Código:</td>
        <td>Nombre:</td>
        <td>Precio:</td>
        <td>Descuento (%):</td>
        <td>Impuesto:</td>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td>Opciones:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="quantity" size="5" title="Cantidad"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="upc" name="codigo" size="12" title="Código" placeholder="744105300000"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="nomprod" name="nombre" size="23" title="Nombre"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="precio" name="price" size="10" title="Precio del producto" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" size="15" title="Descuento" placeholder="0.00%"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="impuestos" class="imp" name="impuestoivi" size="15" title="Impuesto de Ventas" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="total" class="imp" name="totalizar" size="15" title="Total de Línea" placeholder="CRC. 0.00" readonly="readonly"/></td>
        <td><a href="#" title="Agregar línea" id="masfilas" class="add_form_field" style="cursor:pointer;">AGREGAR</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="70%" align="center" border="1" id="mytable" class="table-bordered table-striped">
 <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
     <td width="70%" align="left" colspan="8"><b>RESUMEN DEL CARRITO</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td width="3%">Cantidad:</td>
        <td width="10%">Código:</td>
        <td width="13%">Nombre:</td>
        <td width="5%">Precio:</td>
        <td width="9%">Descuento (%):</td>
        <td width="10%">Impuesto:</td>
        <td width="10%">Total:</td>
        <td colspan="2" width="10%">Opciones:</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="20%" align="left" border="1">
 <tr>
     <td>Subtotal</td>
        <td><span id="enviar_aqui">CRC. 0.00</span></td><!--Me lo manda vacio-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>- Descuento</td>
        <td>CRC. 0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Impuesto</td>
        <td>CRC. 0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Venta Total</td>
        <td>CRC. 0.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```